# Disable Auto Update JDK 7 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, jdk

I have installed JDK 7 in Ubuntu via following commands

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The installed JDK version was **1.7.0_76**. After 2  or 3 weeks, when I check the JDK version, it shows me **1.7.0_80**.

I'm guessing, it happened because of the Auto-Update feature of Java.

Is there any way to disable auto update feature of JAVA/JDK for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable automated software updates? Do you like security flaws?

Comment: I did imported certain SSL certs into jvm's keystore when I setup the java at first. Later I found out, after the update it also updates the jvm keystore and the certificates I imported where not there.. That's the one reason.